# "load" event for dynamically added image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, web

I'm using a 3rd party ad provider on my web page. The ad provider injects an image to a div I configured with a certain id. I'd like to attach a `load` or `ready` event to that image. Note: I can't tell when the image is added to the DOM.

I tried using jquery:

```
$('body').on("load", "img", function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

And this:

```
$("img").on("load", function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.target == document.querySelector("#myDivId img")) {
        console.log(event.target);
    }
});
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: `onload` event doesn't bubble, then it cannot be delegated. However, you can capture it at any static parent level on browsers which support capturing phase. See e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/yb4Luhyu/

Comment: FYI, this is not valid: `document.getElementById("myDivId img")`

Comment: @A.Wolff - I corrected the question. tnx.

Comment: @SharonHaimPour `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, you probably mean `querySelector` or just use jQuery.

Comment: @A.Wolff you should write an answer your analysis is spot on.

Comment: you can use static `div` and by `if ( $('#myfav').children().length > 0 ) {
     // do something
}`  will tell you out side html is injected

Comment: Does it resize the div when it injects the image? If the div is set to auto width/height, it's CSS attributes will change - so you can monitor that with 'resize' then fire an event.